# RoR if .. else statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, if-statement, switch-statement

I am trying to return a value back to my view, though not having much success

## error

undefined local variable or method `schedule' for #

## model

```
    def win_lose_tie
    if schedule.for.to_i == schedule.against.to_i then
      :tie
    elsif schedule.for.to_i > schedule.against.to_i ? :win : :lose
    end
  end
```

## helper

```
    def win_lose_tie_display(value)
    case value
      when :win
        "W"
      when :lose
        "L"
      when :tie
        "T"
      else
        "unknown win/lose/tie value"
    end
  end
```

## view

```
<%= win_lose_tie_display(schedule.win_lose_tie) %>
```

all of which returns the following error

NameError in Schedules#index

Showing /Users/****/Sites/rails_projects/****/app/views/schedules/index.html.erb where line #46 raised:

```
43:           <% @schedules.each do |schedule| %>
44:               <tr>
45:                 <td><%= schedule.event %></td>
46:                 <td><strong><%= win_lose_tie_display(schedule.win_lose_tie) %></strong> <%=  schedule.for %> &mdash; <%= schedule.against %></td>
47:                 <td><%= schedule.opponent %></td>
48:                 <td><%= schedule.date.to_formatted_s(:event_date) %>
49:                 </td>
```

any help of this would be great

thanks in advance

Comment: You need to provide more information about the error. Click on Application Trace or Full Trace, the first few lines should provide the necessary information. Your `win_lose_tie` looks very awkward. Try to refactor it to have more lines or at least more braces.

Comment: application trace returns the following `app/models/schedule.rb:12:in `win_lose_tie'
app/views/schedules/index.html.erb:46:in `_app_views_schedules_index_html_erb___1705540283_2185334800'
app/views/schedules/index.html.erb:43:in `each'
app/views/schedules/index.html.erb:43:in `_app_views_schedules_index_html_erb___1705540283_2185334800'
app/controllers/schedules_controller.rb:7:in `index'

Comment: @ChristophPetschnig I have refactored the code, and included some more information

Comment: Is this your Schedule model up there? In this case, in your `win_lose_tie` method, exchange `schedule` with `self`. I'll post this as the answer if it solves your issue.

Comment: @blackbird07 that worked, after redoing the if..else statement, ive updated the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `win_lose_tie` method, exchange `schedule` with `self`.

This is because `win_lose_tie` is an instance method of a schedule object. You are already in the context of the schedule object, so there is no need to write `schedule.`. In fact, that would reference `*your_schedule_object*.schedule`, which does not exist.

As a site note: Since you only read values, you can even completely omit the `self`. However, if you assign values, the `self` is required.